# load ePub book via URL to iBook on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, sdk, epub, ibooks

as i know the iBook App on iPad can read so called ePub Books. Now a customer want's that we develop an App, where his customers can browse his "store" and download the Books directly to iBooks.

Any Idea if this is possible? The part of writing the app and downloading the ePub Archive to the device isn't a big problem. The question is, is it possible to tell the iBook App to load the downloaded ePub Book? Or is there a way in SDK to hand over a url to the iBook-App so that the App starts and downloads the book itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you load the epub file in mobile safari, it will prompt you to download it into iBooks.